# Getting an error when listing mailbox of Office365 with imapflow in nodejs

Tags: node.js, office365, imap, imapflow

I got an error when a user of my app try to list all the mailbox of a Microsoft mail account.

The error :

```
{"response":{"tag":"7","command":"BAD","attributes":[{"type":"TEXT","value":"LSUB failed."}]},"responseStatus":"BAD","responseText":"LSUB failed."}
```

He performed a login and get an access token and a refresh token without a problem.
It is strange because he can send new mail and open some mail but every time he tries to list his boxes the error come back.
If the user uses another mail software, he manages to list his mailboxes.

My code :

```js
function getConnection() {
    const ipaddr = '';
    const port = '';
    const isSSL = true;
    const mail = '';
    const mailPass = '';
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        let client = new ImapFlow(
            {
                logger: true,
                host: ipaddr,
                port: port,
                secure: isSSL,
                tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                },
                {
                    user: mail,
                    pass: mailPass
                }
            }
        );
        client.connect().then(() => {
            resolve(client);
        });
    });
}

const imap = await getConnection();
const list = await imap.list();
// I got the error here
```

Node v12.14.0
Imapflow v1.0.98
Typescript v4.7.4

I checked in Azure AD if everything was ok and the user did it as well in his account.
I don't know if the error comes from my configuration or that of the user's account.

If anyone has any idea why this error is appearing ?

Comment: A quick web search looks like maybe Exchange no longer supports LSUB (which is weird.)  You should be able to do ‘* LIST’ instead, but I don’t know how to get node.js to emit that command.

Comment: Looks like the node.js command is getBoxes vs getSubscribedBoxes() (note: that’s for the imap module, not imapflow)

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug asking for an option to not use ‘lsub’, since the API is not clear that it’s going to use it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that Exchange doesn't support LSUB. We have other users who are in the same Microsoft account group and they don't have this problem.

Comment: Okay, let me rephase, there are enough reports on the internet of people having trouble with `LSUB` that it appears microsoft has introduced a bug with it affecting some accounts, and returning errors on the simplest possible `LSUB` command.  The work around would be to just use `LIST`, but your library does not seem to have that capability built in.

Comment: For example, here's a report with a trace where the most basic LSUB command is being sent: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/80723/lsub-failed-with-office-365-imap-server